# Are subbases preserved under homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition**.If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces,then a *homeomorphism* between $X$ and $Y$ is a bijection $\varphi:X\rightarrow Y$ that is continuous and has a continuous inverse $\varphi^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X.$

$\varphi$ is a homeomorphism of $(R,\tau)$ onto $(R^{'},\tau^{'}),$ whether we have $\varphi$ maps every subasis of $(R,\tau)$ onto a  subasis $(R^{'},\tau^{'})$?

Comment: Homeomorphisms preserve everything involving open sets.